# How to solve java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: E6100000?

Tags: java, spring, spatial

I have a problem with this error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: E6100000  when i try to log in to app i have this error and i dont know why ?
I have database in sqlserver connection is good but i cant go to my mian site in app can someone help ?

```
2021-02-08 17:04:24.809 ERROR 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: E6100000
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:877) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:350) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2807) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1545) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1477) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1377) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:644) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:854) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2382) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2368) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2198) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2193) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1248) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:890) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at pl.edu.wszib.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.getUserByLogin(UserDAOImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at pl.edu.wszib.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticationUser(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at pl.edu.wszib.controller.usercontroller.LoginController.authenticateUser(LoginController.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

my user class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="dbo",name = "UserApp")
public class UserApp implements UserDetails  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUser;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private Point location;
    private String role;
    private String locationName;
```

My authentication

```
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements IAuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;


    public AuthenticationServiceImpl(IUserDAO userDAO){
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticationUser(UserApp userApp){
        UserApp userAppFromDb = this.userDAO.getUserByLogin(userApp.getUsername());
        return userAppFromDb != null && userAppFromDb.getPassword().equals(DigestUtils.md5Hex(userApp.getPassword()));
    }
}
```

login controller to log in to app

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  String authenticateUser(@ModelAttribute("userModel") UserApp userApp, Model model){
        boolean authResult = this.authenticationService.authenticationUser(userApp);
        if(authResult){
            System.out.println("logged  !!");
            this.sessionObject.setUserApp(userApp);
            System.out.println(userApp);
            return "rentAppPage";
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage","error data!!!");
            model.addAttribute("userModel",new UserApp());
            return "login";
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain why i cant log in to app i have a user in db but i cant and i get this error ?

Comment: It seems to be a deserialization issue. Might it be because of classname obfuscation?

Comment: i have class name in app the same as in database

Comment: What is `o.a.c.c.C` is that not the class qualified name? If you want to see exactly what's causing the deserialization issue then you could put a breakpoint in `org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize` and debug.

Comment: can you write where i have org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize?

Comment: Did you not read your exception? It's in the stack trace, if you include [the sources of `hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.6.Final/) then you should be able to navigate to it and add a breakpoint so you can look at the data when the exception occurs.

Comment: i read my error i see 3 blue lines on  at ```pl.edu.wszib.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.getUserByLogin(UserDAOImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
 at pl.edu.wszib.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticationUser(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
 at pl.edu.wszib.controller.usercontroller.LoginController.authenticateUser(LoginController.java:59) ~[classes/:na]``` i debug on this site but i  dont see any error

Comment: What is the source of `pl.edu.wszib.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.getUserByLogin(UserDAOImpl.java:50)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please learn to read and trace your exceptions...

This stack trace frame is telling you that there's an issue in reading the ObjectInputStream because you received the stream headers `E610` and `0000` instead of whatever it's expecting (probably `ACED` and `0005`).

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: E6100000
at
java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:877)java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:877)

protected void readStreamHeader()
    throws IOException, StreamCorruptedException
{
    short s0 = bin.readShort();
    short s1 = bin.readShort();
    if (s0 != STREAM_MAGIC || s1 != STREAM_VERSION) {
        throw new StreamCorruptedException(
            String.format("invalid stream header: %04X%04X", s0, s1));
    }
}
```

A reason for this could be that something didn't read the stream correctly and there are leftover bytes or that something isn't writing correctly.

Your solution is to put breakpoints and debug wherever you are messing with this object stream to find where it's going wrong.